# How to plot spatial points (vector) on a raster file (landsat img) in R

Tags: r, spatial, raster, projection, points

I want to plot spatial points (sp) on a landsat compository, plotting landsat works and plotting the sp as well, but it does not work together. I am quite sure that I somehow don't get the overwriting of the projection/coordinate system, but don't know what I am doing wrong. Googleing didn't help, so I ask you.

Here is the code:

```
coords_glaciers <- data.frame(x = prec_year$latitude, y = prec_year$longitude)
head(coords_glaciers)

         x        y
1 30.69800 95.10474
2 30.69628 95.09544
3 30.69173 95.04394
4 30.68793 95.08615
5 30.68799 95.20155
6 30.68472 95.21425

pts_glaciers <- SpatialPoints(coords = coords_glaciers)
pts_glaciers

class       : SpatialPoints 
features    : 865 
extent      : 29.50121, 30.82512, 94.24684, 96.19304  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : NA 
proj <- projection(landsat)
proj
[1] "+proj=utm +zone=46 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs"

pts_glaciers <- SpatialPoints(coords = coords_glaciers, proj4string = CRS(proj))
pts_glaciers

class       : SpatialPoints 
features    : 865 
extent      : 29.50121, 30.82512, 94.24684, 96.19304  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=utm +zone=46 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs 

plotRGB(landsat, r=5, g=4,b=3)
plot(pts_glaciers, add =TRUE)
```

Comment: Try `pts_glaciers <- spTransform(pts_glaciers, CRS(proj))` from `rgdal`

Comment: Hi Djack, unfortunately your solution does not look different.... I already loaded, rgdal, sp and raster before.

Comment: What is the extent of `landsat` ?

Comment: > landsat
class       : RasterStack 
dimensions  : 7021, 8061, 56596281, 9  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution  : 30, 30  (x, y)
extent      : 599685, 841515, 3249585, 3460215  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=utm +zone=46 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the solution is:

```
coords_glaciers <- data.frame(x = prec_year$longitude, y = prec_year$latitude)

coordinates(coords_glaciers) <- c("x","y")

proj4string(coords_glaciers) <- CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84") 

pts_glaciers <- spTransform(coords_glaciers, CRS("+proj=utm +zone=46 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs"))
```

Comment: the second command does not work, so i entered "+proj=utm +zone=46 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs" so the command went well, but the problem is still the same. When I plot the pts_glaciers and the landsat image separately they seem to have totally different dimensions... and the adding of the pts_glacier won'twork

Comment: Ok now I get it, you need to switch latitude and longitude in coords_glaciers

Comment: Haha, stupid of me.... Thanks for the info, but anyway, the problem won't solve. When looking at the spatial points and the landsat img, they have different extents, pts_glacier has the geographic coordinates and landsat the UTM coordinates. Changing the extent only works for the landsat img but that totally destroys the scale and the points, even though they can be added over the landsat scene dont fit...

Comment: My answer project pts_glaciers in UTM and last time I checked it fits the extent of landsat so it should work

Comment: yes, you are totally right, I just made a litte further mistake, but now it works. THANKS A LOT!!!

Comment: You re welcome. Consider accepting the answer to inform the community that the issue is resolved.